# Index-match across range to pull result on different tab

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column in a tab that I am trying to pull the data from column A in a different tab when it finds the number in B:F

So in one tab I would have 03303 in Column D2, and then I'm trying to have it return "SECOND" when it finds 03303 in column E. Simple if I do
=INDEX(PG!$A$1:$A$8,MATCH(D2,PG!$E$1:$E$8,0)), but that wouldn't work for anything else, so I need it to search through the range B:F.

```
 FIRST  01234               
 SECOND 03300   03301   03302   03303   03309
 THIRD  03310               
 FOURTH 01597   01598   01599   02850   02851
 FIFTH  00800   00801   00802   00809   
 SIXTH  02600               
 SEVENTH    04245               
 EIGHTH 01020
```

I've tried searching through past questions, but I'm not exactly sure if their questions are similar to mine. A lot of them want rows summed, etc. I just want column A pulled when my column D on different tab matches a number in B:F

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use AGGREGATE instead of MATCH.

```
=INDEX(PG!A:A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(PG!$B$1:$F$8)/(PG!$B$1:$F$8=D2),1))
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry to bug you once more Scott, but any idea why this isn't working?

=IF(D2="","",IF(ISNA(INDEX(PG!$A$1:$A$54,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(PG!$B$1:$II$54)/(PG!$B$1:$II$54=D2),1))),"INVALID PG",INDEX(PG!$A$1:$A$54,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(PG!$B$1:$II$54)/(PG!$B$1:$II$54=D2),1))))

I'm trying to make it say "INVALID PG" when it doesn't find D2 in the range. D2="","" excludes blanks.

Comment: Try this: `=IF(D2="","",IFERROR(INDEX(PG!A:A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(​PG!$B$1:$II$54)/(​PG!$B$1:$II$54=D2),1)),"INVALID PG"))`